# Submit email form without page refresh NO JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to make form that submits without a page refresh.  I cannot use jQuery to accomplish this.  I can't seem to find any solution anywhere that DOESN'T mention it, so I just want to know what I am doing wrong with what I have so far, and how I can fix it.

html

```
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
<fieldset>
<ol>
<li><label for="email">Email Address</label><input class="text" id="email" name="email" size="30" type="text"></li>
<li><label for="firstName">First Name</label><input class="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" size="30" type="text"></li>
<li><label for="lastName">Last Name</label><input class="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" size="30" type="text"></li>
<li><label for="message">Message</label><textarea cols="40"  id="message" name="message" rows="20"></textarea></li>
</ol>
<input class="button" id="contactSubmit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Ajax/JS

```
function observeEvent(target, eventName, observerFunction, useCapture){
    if (target.addEventListener) {
        target.addEventListener(eventName, observerFunction, useCapture);
    } else if (target.attachEvent) {
        target.attachEvent("on" + eventName, observerFunction);
    }
}


function start() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById("success");

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "processor.php", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            contentDiv.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert('message sent!');
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
    xmlhttp.send("email=" + email +"&firstName=" + firstName + "&lastName=" + lastName + "&message=" + message);
}

observeEvent(window,"load",function() {
    var btn=document.getElementById("contactSubmit");
    observeEvent(btn,"click",start);
});
```

PHP for good measure

```
<?php

$fName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'xxx@xxx.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'FROM: ' . $fName . ' ' . $lName . ' Email: ' . $email . 'Message: '. $message;
$headers = 'From: ' . $to . "\r\n";

$mailRegex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/';

if (preg_match($mailRegex, $email)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Your email was sent!"; 
}
```

Comment: your email validation will fail a lot of valid email addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!!!!

I wasn't giving any values to be sent from the form.  I fixed it by making my start() function look like this:

```
function start() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById("success");

    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var fName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    var lName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
    var mes = document.getElementById('message').value;

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "processor.php", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            contentDiv.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert('message sent!');
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
    xmlhttp.send('email=' + encodeURIComponent(email) + '&firstName=' + encodeURIComponent(fName) + '&lastName=' + encodeURIComponent(lName) + '&message=' + encodeURIComponent(mes));

    return false;
}
```

I had tried to use the values from a validating function beforehand, but there was a scope issue related to that.  This works!!!  I'm a real programmer (sort of)!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is just to have an iframe in your document and hide it with CSS.  Give the iframe a name and then set a target attribute on your form which refers to your hidden iframe.

This will cause the form to post inside the hidden iframe and the whole page will not reload.

No javascript is even required.

If you need to process the result of the post, just use the onload event on the iframe to detect and process the output of the php page, which is now in the iframe.

Comment: Cool, but it actually NEEDS to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There two ways to fix it:

- Expression in form `onsubmit` attribute should return `false`;
- You should call `event.preventDefault` method in handler of form `submit` event or input[type="submit"] `click` event.

Comment: Try this `onsubmit="validate(this);return false;"` on form element

Comment: Also you can disable default behavior of submit button by calling event.preventDefault() in clickEvent handler